# Connecting from Flash to IRC server

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript, irc

I'm looking for a way to connect from flash to an IRC server.
The common solution was to use a tunneling service which uses comet/websockets like:

1. pusher.com
2. tech.kaazing.com/documentation/dragonfire/howto-irc.html
3. www.lightstreamer.com

However, since this product is meant for flash, can I connect directly to the irc server instead of going through the tunneling service in the middle?
One proof of concept that i found was [lightirc](http://www.lightirc.com/), but they doesn't make it clear if they serve as a long-polling proxy in the middle or the client connects directly to the irc server. The only thing they mention is that I should put crossdomain.xml on the irc server side to bypass the flash security setting, but does it means the client connects to it directly?

Any idea if